# How to get git to ignore line white spacing

Tags: git, linux-kernel, kernel

When merging files I keep getting `<<<<HEAD` problems where I believe it is being added because of white spacing here is a sample file:

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_TIME=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_U32=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CLASSIFY=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNMARK=y
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNSECMARK=y
>>>>>>> e2f24dded0a2c63a99f439dc422f7887c2d1d5e5
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_IDLETIMER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_MARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NFLOG=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NFQUEUE=y
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_SECMARK=y
>>>>>>> e2f24dded0a2c63a99f439dc422f7887c2d1d5e5
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TCPMSS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TPROXY=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TRACE=y
CONFIG_NET_CLS_ACT=y
CONFIG_NET_CLS_U32=y
CONFIG_NET_EMATCH=y
CONFIG_NET_EMATCH_U32=y
CONFIG_NET_KEY=y
CONFIG_NET_SCHED=y
CONFIG_NET_SCH_HTB=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=y
```

I'm very new to handling Android kernels, but getting a drift of what to do, I'm basically trying to merge [my branch](https://github.com/MikeUYSCUTI/surnia_msm8916/tree/nougat-stable) with this [commit and source](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git/+/e2f24dded0a2c63a99f439dc422f7887c2d1d5e5)

I'm using this merge in the command line git `merge -X ignore-all-space -X patience` So maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `Conflict` occurring while merging `nougat-stable` (the branch you are merging ). You need to `resolve conflicts first` then do `git add` and `commit`.

Here, `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNSECMARK=y` and `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_SECMARK=y` lines are coming from `nougat-stable` (reason of conflict). If you want to keep the lines then accept `theirs` otherwise `ours`.

```
$ git checkout --theirs -- .                # keep the two lines
Or,
$ git checkout --ours -- .                  # ignore the two lines

$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Fix conflicts'
$ git push origin HEAD
```